# Возвращаемое значение из очереди, если она пустая

Tags: c++, классы, очередь

```
class queue
{
private:
    static const int max = 3;
    int ary[max];
    int head;
    int tail;
public:
    queue()
    {
        head = -1;
        tail = -1;
    }
    void put(int a)
    {
        ++head;
        if (head == max)
            head = 0;
        ary[head] = a;
    }
    int get()
    {
        if (tail == head)
        {
            return NULL;
        }
        else {
            ++tail;
            if (tail == max)
                tail = 0;
            return ary[tail];
        }

    }
};

int main()
{
    queue z;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        z.put(i);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cout<<z.get() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Как осуществить выход из очереди, если она пустая ?

```
if (tail == head)
            {
                return NULL;
            }
```

Вот тут возникает проблема. Если в очереди нет элементов, то возвращаю NULL, а хотелось бы ничего не возвращать, но не могу т.к ф-ция должна возвращать тип int.
Как это реализовать ?

Comment: Вот и возвращайте всегда указатель (его всегда можно разыменовать), а не значение.

Comment: Можно метод добавить для проверки наличия данных.

Answer (score 3):

> Вот тут возникает проблема. Если в очереди нет элементов, то возвращаю NULL, а хотелось бы ничего не возвращать, но не могу т.к ф-ция должна возвращать тип int. Как это реализовать ?

Если формат функции менять нельзя (только так как предложено в вопросе), то единственный вариант обработки "ситуаций" - бросание исключений и их последующая обработка извне, а-ля:

```
if (tail == head && head == nullptr) throw my_queue_exception("empty");
```

Comment: Если ситуация пустой очереди не исключительная, то лучше обойтись без исключений.